# Query failed data not inserted to the DB

Tags: php, postgresql

**Those are the fields on my DB**

- `partamento int`
- `codigocurso int`
- `diurno int`
- `contacto int`
- `pos_laboral int`
- `contacto2 int`
- `proc_por int`

I’ve been trying to fix this error since yesterday but I cannot figure out where is the error.
**

```
foreach ($diurno as $userId) {
        $data .= "(".$id.",".$grdid.",".$userId.",".$contacto.",".$pos_laboral.",".$contacto2.",".$idd.")";
    }
    
    $data = rtrim($data, ',');
    $sql = "insert into cursosprogramas (departamento, codigocurso, diurno, contacto, pos_laboral, contacto2, proc_por) values (".$data.");";
    echo $sql;
```

**the error**

> insert into cursosprogramas (departamento, codigocurso, diurno, contacto, pos_laboral, contacto2, proc_por) values ((100,120,7,646,5,363,2)(100,120,4,646,5,363,2));Query failed.

Comment: You are missing a comma between data sets.

Comment: Also, you should also learn about [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) with [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4712113/5827005).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing a comma between data sets, and you also don't need parenthesis around them all. You are already using `rtrim()` to remove the very last comma, but you aren't actually adding the comma at the end of the data set.

```
foreach ($diurno as $userId) {
    
    //add a comma at the end
    //note you can write variables directly into a string that is wrapped with double quotes
    $data .= "('$id', '$grdid', '$userId', '$contacto', '$pos_laboral', '$contacto2', '$idd'),";
}

//this gets rid of the very last comma in the string
$data = rtrim($data, ',');

//remove parenthesis around `$data`
$sql = "insert into cursosprogramas (departamento, codigocurso, diurno, contacto, pos_laboral, contacto2, proc_por) values {$data};";
echo $sql;
```

NOTE: [Little Bobby](http://bobby-tables.com/) says [this code MAY be at risk for SQL Injection Attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/) depending on how the variables inside of `$data` are created. Learn about [Prepared Statements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) with [parameterized queries](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4712113/5827005).

Comment: @HQweb Glad that I could help

Comment: I added more columns on my table and I tried to insert data on the table and I got query failed, so I tried to troubleshoot and I got this: postgres=# insert into cursosprogramas (departamento,codigocurso,curso,codigo,disciplina,legenda,ano,r,t,tp,pl,ts,total,ms,diurno,contacto,pos_laboral,contacto2,proc_por)values (100,2121,Medicina,5235,sgsgs, s,1º,1º,4,4,4,4,4, 4,5,646464,5,6363, 2),(100,2121,Medicina,5235,sgsgs, s,1º,1º,4,4,4,4,4, 4,4,646464,5,6363, 2);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "§"LINE 1: ...roc_por) values (100,2121,Medicina,5235,sgsgs, s,1§,1§,4,4,4...

Comment: Those are the fields on my DB departamento int codigocurso int curso text codigo int disciplina text legenda text ano text r text  From column t to column proc_por they are integer

Comment: @HQweb Try my update, I removed the single quotes without thinking about it.

Comment: Sorry, where did you remove it?

Comment: @HQweb Before my update, I didn't have single quotes around the variables in `$data`, these are needed because some of your variables are strings and not just numbers.

Comment: it still the samepostgres=# insert into cursosprogramas (departamento, codigocurso, curso, codigo, disciplina, legenda, ano, r, t, tp, pl, ts, total, ms, diurno, contacto, pos_laboral, contacto2, proc_por) values (100,2121,Medicina,5235,sgsgs,s,1º,1º,4,4,4,4,4,4,5,646464,5,6363,2),(100,2121,Medicina,5235,sgsgs, s,1º,1º,4,4,4,4,4, 4,4,646464,5,6363, 2);
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "§"
LINE 1: ...roc_por) values (100,2121,Medicina,5235,sgsgs, s,1§,1§,4,4,4...

Comment: foreach ($diurno as $userId) {
   $data .= '('.$id.','.$grdid.','.$curso.','.$codigo.','.$disciplina.',
   '.$legenda.','.$ano.','.$r.','.$t.','.$tp.','.$pl.','.$ts.','.$total.',
   '.$ms.','.$userId.','.$contacto.','.$pos_laboral.','.$contacto2.',
   '.$idd.'),';
  }
like this?

Comment: I've made some changes on my form, I decided that the pos_laboral will also be multiple insert on my form. How can I implement those changes on the foreach? Because I just noticed that I can't do like: foreach ($diurno as $userId and $pos_laboral as $userId2). How is it supposed to be?

Comment: @HQweb Just do the other loop separately.

Comment: i did it like this foreach ($pos_laboral as $userIdd) but it is saying undefined variable userIdd

Comment: @HQweb Shouldn't it just be `$userId`?

Comment: Well, it can be another name

Comment: foreach ($diurno as $userId) {
 $data .= "('$id', '$grdid', '$userId', '$contacto', '$pos_laboral', '$contacto2', '$idd'),";
//the pos_lavoral on the first foreach will give a error like: array to string conversation
// and if I change to new it will be undefined variable new.
}
foreach ($pos_laboral as $new) {
  $data .= "('$id', '$grdid', '$userId', '$contacto', '$new, '$contacto2', '$idd'),";
}
$data = rtrim($data, ',');
$sql = "insert into cursosprogramas (departamento, codigocurso, diurno, contacto, pos_laboral, contacto2, proc_por) values {$data};";
echo $sql;

Comment: Sorry, you're probably going to need to post a new question.

Comment: Okay @GrumpyCrouton

Answer (score 1):

You need a comma between the value tuples. Try a comma at the end of line two like this:

```
foreach ($diurno as $userId) {
$data .= "(".$id.",".$grdid.",".$userId.",".$contacto.",".$pos_laboral.",".$contacto2.",".$idd."),";
}

$data = rtrim($data, ',');
$sql = "insert into cursosprogramas (departamento, codigocurso, diurno, contacto, pos_laboral, contacto2, proc_por) values (".$data.");";
echo $sql;
```

Comment: This answer currently fails if any of the values are strings with a space in it